# Changing permissions for file

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint

I get this error when I try to change permission for this directory in linux mint.
 can any one help me?

The error is:

```
   chown: cannot read directory ‘/tmp/ecryptfs.LicIw3Py/’: Permission denied
```

I seriously need this help. so any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need to become a superuser, aka an admin. You can do this temporarily with sudo (superuser do).
Usage is thus:

```
sudo chown -R myusername /tmp/ecryptfs.LicIw3Py/
```

it will ask you for a password. Man page for sudo [here](http://man.cx/sudo), a better explanation is [here](http://xkcd.com/149/)

[image: Proper User Policy apparently means Simon Says]